# Error in id OnChange

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function in javascript that is invoked with an onChange.
All good when it is one

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" onchange="opert(<?php echo $fetch["id_prod"] ?>,1)" id="name" value="<?php echo $fetch["name_prod"]; ?>">
```

Now, when I put it in a while it gives me id conflict, how do I put the same id to all my input inside the while?

Comment: Can you specify more what you want to achieve? It is not so clear..

Comment: what does `put same id to all my input inside the while` mean??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of onChange, you can get the product ID by input class after putting the "id_prod" in data attribute.

```
<input class="form-control opert" type="text" data-opert_val="<?php echo  $fetch["id_prod"] ?>" id="name" value="<?php echo $fetch["name_prod"]; ?>">


$(".opert").on('blur', function(){
  var id_prod = $(this).attr('data-opert_val');
  var name_prod = $(this).val();
});
```

Hope this help you.